# robots.txt for public facing knowledge articles?

Tags: knowledge, articles

Is there a way to modify or change the robots.txt for our public facing KB articles, so I can change which search engines can crawl them, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On force.com sites you can create a custom robots.txt file and modify .

Here are some the links to assist

[Help Resource From SFDC](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_configure_seo.htm&type=0)

[Best Practices For SEO](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo_best_practices.htm&type=0)

[Setting Up SEO](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_seo.htm&type=0)

In nut shell to summarize from these docs ,you will need a visualforce page with below lines of code

```
<apex:page contentType="text/plain">
 User-agent: *
Disallow: /   # hides everything from ALL bots
Allow: /<path-prefix-1>/s  # add path you want to open to bots
Allow: /<path-prefix-2>/s  # add path you want to open to bots
Sitemap: http://<community_URL>/s/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://<community_URL>/<sub_path>/s/sitemap.xml
</apex:page>
```

And then attach this visualforce to site settings using sites record .

Comment: Thanks Mohith. If I create a visualforce page, how do I associate it with the public KB Articles?

Comment: You associate with the site .Then in that indicate path for articles in the Sitemap variable shown above